# C++ TGA reading fails

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, tga

i'm using the java method below to write an android.graphics.Bitmap to tga, i've opened the photo in photoshop and it's allright. in native i have to load and display this image with opengl, but the loading of image is incorrect and i see incorrect colors on the screen, the c++ tga loader is below. anybody has any ideea what's the problem?

java write tga method:

```
public static void writeTGA(Bitmap src, String path) throws IOException {

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(src.getRowBytes() * src.getHeight());
    src.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
    boolean alpha = src.hasAlpha();
    byte[] data;

    byte[] pixels = buffer.array();
    if (pixels.length != src.getWidth() * src.getHeight() * (alpha ? 4 : 3))
        throw new IllegalStateException();

    data = new byte[pixels.length];

    for(int i=0;i < pixels.length; i += 4){// rgba -> bgra
        data[i] = pixels[i+2];
        data[i+1] = pixels[i+1];
        data[i+2] = pixels[i];
        data[i+3] = pixels[i+3];
    }

    byte[] header = new byte[18];
    header[2] = 2; // uncompressed, true-color image
    header[12] = (byte) ((src.getWidth() >> 0) & 0xFF);
    header[13] = (byte) ((src.getWidth() >> 8) & 0xFF);
    header[14] = (byte) ((src.getHeight() >> 0) & 0xFF);
    header[15] = (byte) ((src.getHeight() >> 8) & 0xFF);
    header[16] = (byte) (alpha ? 32 : 24); // bits per pixel
    header[17] = (byte) ((alpha ? 8 : 0) | (1 << 4));

    File file = new File(path);
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
    raf.write(header);
    raf.write(data);
    raf.setLength(raf.getFilePointer()); // trim
    raf.close();
}
```

tga 18 bit header c++ :

```
typedef struct _tgaheader {
    BYTE IDLength;        /* 00h  Size of Image ID field */
    BYTE ColorMapType;    /* 01h  Color map type */
    BYTE ImageType;       /* 02h  Image type code */
    BYTE CMapStart[2];       /* 03h  Color map origin */
    BYTE CMapLength[2];      /* 05h  Color map length */
    BYTE CMapDepth;       /* 07h  Depth of color map entries */
    WORD XOffset;         /* 08h  X origin of image */
    WORD YOffset;         /* 0Ah  Y origin of image */
    WORD Width;           /* 0Ch  Width of image */
    WORD Height;          /* 0Eh  Height of image */
    BYTE PixelDepth;      /* 10h  Image pixel size */
    BYTE ImageDescriptor; /* 11h  Image descriptor byte */
} TGAHEADER;
```

tga loader method:

```
void TgaFormat:: LoadImage(const char *path) {
    FILE* filePtr = fopen(path, "rb");
    long imageSize;
    short pixel_size;
    unsigned char colorSwap;

    // Open the TGA file.
    if( filePtr == NULL){
        LOGI("cannot find Tga File!");
        return;
    }
    fread(&file_header, 1, sizeof(TGAHEADER), filePtr);
    short sz = sizeof(TGAHEADER);
    // 2 (uncompressed RGB image), 3 (uncompressed black-and-white images).
    if (file_header.ImageType != 2 ){
        fclose(filePtr);
        LOGI("this file is not a TGA!");
        return;
    }

    // Color mode -> 3 = BGR, 4 = BGRA.
    pixel_size = file_header.PixelDepth / 8;
    imageSize = file_header.Width * file_header.Height * pixel_size;

    m_rgba_data = (BYTE* )malloc( sizeof(BYTE) * imageSize );

    if( fread(m_rgba_data, 1, imageSize, filePtr) != imageSize ) {
        fclose(filePtr);
        return ;
    }
    fclose(filePtr);

    // Change from BGRA to RGBA so OpenGL can read the image data.
    for (int imageIdx = 0; imageIdx < imageSize; imageIdx += pixel_size) {
        colorSwap = m_rgba_data[imageIdx];
        m_rgba_data[imageIdx] = m_rgba_data[imageIdx + 2];
        m_rgba_data[imageIdx + 2] = colorSwap;
    }
}
```

after reading the tga file in android native and rendered with opengles
[image]

the generated qr code into sdcard the opened with photoshop
[image]

Comment: You could try `asserting` that your TGA header really is 18 bytes and that your compiler hasn't padded anything...

Comment: i've made ' int sz = sizeof(TGAHEADER); ' then debugging, and sz takes value 18;

Comment: So the geometry and shapes of things in the image are correct, but the colours are wrong? Consistently wrong or randomly?

Comment: i put a random .bmp file as texture on the same shape and it binds & renders ok. this tga loader is very strange.. i have width, height, bit depth, file type OK, then it alocates the vector with the correct size.. i can't understand why i have strange colors..

Comment: yes, the geometry is correct, and colors are wrong, not quit consistently, i can se 2x of my image, the left one has the odd line of pixel, the right one has the even one

Comment: If you are on Linux you will have ImageMagick and can make a red TGA file with `convert -size 640x480 xc:red RED.TGA` or a cyan-magenta gradient image with `convert -size 640x480 gradient:cyan-magenta GRADIENT.TGA`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144503/discussion-between-stoica-mircea-and-mark-setchell).

Comment: Sorry, I cannot at the moment.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the image please?

Comment: i've attached images to this post

Comment: You have attached photos of images, not the actual image you created in Java. If the images you generate in Java display correctly in Photoshop, there is no need to show the Java code - it must be correct! If the images do not load into Android, then there is something wrong with your Android code and you should generate some very simple images as I suggested with ImageMagick to debug your Android code.

Comment: the second photo was writed in java, then open in photoshop. i found the mistake. as i was been thinking, i got an offset, but not in writing/reading process, into the upload to gpu:

i had 
"glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB.....);"
 instead of 
"glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA....);"
because my pixel size is 4 (RGBA) not 3 (RGB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second photo was writed in java, then open in photoshop. i found the mistake. as i was been thinking, i've got a wrong offset, but not in writing/reading process.

into the upload to gpu:

I had

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB.....);
```

instead of

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA....);
```

because my pixel size is 4 (RGBA) not 3 (RGB).